# Is there a Wordpress method or PlugIn to call JS function from <body> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I have two JS functions I want to call, in a wordpress site, from an external .js file. When writing the functions, I called one from the HTML document's  tag, but didn't think of how to actually apply this in WordPress.

I see several PlugIns for altering headers/footers, but am just wondering if there's an option for the . Below is a sample which shows JS being called from my  tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>SO Question</title>
</head>
<body onload="destroyEarth()">
    <h1>Article title</h1><br>
    <p>Article text</p><br>
    <script async src="extFile.js"></script>
    <p>
       <a href="#"" onclick="dscntFuniture();" id="FSP" name="FSP">
       <img src="https://i.imgur.com/4LtRreH.png" id="RRU" name="RCU"/>
       </a>
    </p>
    <p>....more article text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I'd like to be able to call destroyEarth() and dscntFuniture(), from extFile.js, in a WP site. Ideally there'd be a Plugin or alternative way of writing the code so that I can implement this.

Edit:

```
<script async src="extFile.js">
    $(document).onload(destroyEarth);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `onload` does it for you:

```
$(document).onload(destroyEarth);
```

There should not be a practical difference between document and body onload event. Both will be triggered when content is loaded.

UPDATED:

add the following code in either header or footer of your website. It does not depend on any library, thanks @Shilly:

```
<script>
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', destroyEarth );
</script>
```

If it does not work, look into developers console for js errors and post them here

Comment: Sorry, I'm not experienced and jQuery is rather new to me. Where do I cite that within my code for it to work? I've added it between the <script> tags but without success. I've appended my original post with an example.

Comment: You could try `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', destroyEarth );` if you are not using jquery. No need to import a new library for one line of code.

Comment: @Shilly, where do I place that? I tried it between my <script> tags and it didn't work. Do I need to alter the .js file in any way for this method to work?

Comment: @Eriks Klotins Apologies for the late response. I appreciate that you're helping me. I did try to add `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', destroyEarth );` to my code and it didn't work. I did reach out to HostGator support and they suggested I contact Elementor, as they ran a test script and it didn't work either (I'm using WP). I'm hoping they get back to me because I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: @JasonB, JS code is executed on your computer and mostly has nothing to do with the server or the hosting provider. Check the console tab on DeveloperTools for any errors. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Comment: @EriksKlotins Hi, I was able to resolve the issue by adjusting the way the function was called in my source code. Thanks for the help though.